# ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-whisper

I am trying to use whisper and pytube to extract the text from a youtube video. even though i install whisper i get the following error.

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from whisper) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

I'm using MacOS Ventura, if anyone has any ideas it would be very helpful, thanks

Previously I had python 11.0, then I installed python 3.9.9 so that whisper can run normally, although I still get the same error as when I had python 11.0

Comment: Are both pythons there? You may have installed the other python but still be using the first one. For instance, you may have to specifically use `python3.9`. Or, setup a python virtual environment, e.g., `python3.9 -m venv some_working_directory` so that "python" would run the version you want. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: There is no `python 11.0`. What command did you use to install? If you are using just `pip`, what is the output of `pip -V`? Make sure you are actually using Python 3.7 - 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing python 3.11 and installing python 3.10.9, it looks like torch is not compatible with python 3.11 on windows

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove all python versions()

1. if you use linux, on your system installed python3.10 or like that by default, and if you need a special version to use for installing, you must set default python version. [solution](https://www.linuxtuto.com/how-to-install-python-3-12-on-ubuntu-22-04/#)
2. in windows, you must remove another versions of python and install only >=3.7 <> <=3.10 versions
3. the best solution for this use python virtualenvironment:

- create with specific python version venv:

```
python3.10 -m venv myvenv
```

- activate venv(linux):

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

- (windows):

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

then you can pip installs

Answer (score -2):

Remove Python 3.11.3 and install Python 3.9 or 3.10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is not necessary to remove 3.11. It is perfectly normal to have multiple versions of Python in your system. The key is making sure to use a virtual env and that Python in that virtual env is using the correct Python version.